# Обновление главного окна

Tags: winapi, c++

Задание: получить высоту и ширину поля ввода, а затем добавить поле Edit на главное окно. Получаю глобальные переменные, добавляю поле Edit, но оно не видно. Я так понимаю, надо как-то обновить окно или заново перестроить. Как и где это делается?

Голый винапи.

После `DialogBox`

```
SendMessage(hWnd, WM_CREATE, 0, 0);
```

в `WM_CREATE`:

```
hEdit = CreateWindowW(TEXT("edit"),TEXT(""),WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP | WS_BORDER,10,10,x,y,hWnd,NULL,hInst,NULL);
```

Далее, пробовал `UpdateWindow(hWnd)` и `InvalidateRect(hWnd,0,1)`. Но его нет. Вместо него появляется мелким шрифтом [].

Comment: MFC или голый винапи?

Comment: "добавляю поле Edit" - а как вы добавляете его?

Comment: В-общем ошибка была в том что при считывании в char-строку она содержала "40506000" при вводе "456". atoi преобразовывала в 4.

Comment: Это из-за юникода

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все правильно работало просто нельзя считывать в char, надо в wchar_t. Нуб я в winapi! ) Просто не привык еще к такому обилию типов.